# Warning C26495 function invocation from constructor to initialize variable, why?

Tags: c++

**Note:** Enable Microsoft Native Recommended Rules in VS.

I am not initializing data members in  constructor/initializer list, instead due to too many data members, these data members are copied within a function and then invoking function from constructor.

Is there any specific reason for this warning message.

**warning C26495:** Variable 'Person::m_id' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).

```
class Person
{
    std::string m_name;
    int m_id; 
    /* Other data members*/

public:

    Person()
    {
        initialize();
    }

    void initialize()
    {
        m_name = "someText";
        m_id = 1;
        /* Other data members initialization*/
    }

};
```

Comment: Why are you not using the initializer list of the constructor?

Comment: Do you get the same warning/error with just these two data members (as shown in this code)? Just wondering how to try to reproduce this

Comment: @Yunnosch I am invoking to initialize variable.

Comment: @melpomene I agree that initializer list is definitely a better choice. Lets say if there  are too many data members, then it looks bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the warning because you don't initialize the member in the constructor or use an initializer list. The fact that you do it in a function call isn't "captured" since it won't check each function call for this simple warnings check. It could quickly become a huge tree of function calls to check.

You probably don't get a warning for your string. This is because when you don't initialize it, it is using its default constructor which constructs an empty string, with a length of zero characters. So your string actually IS initialized. But for basic types like *int* there is no such default "constructor"

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

Comment: What if `initialize` was declared `inline` ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust actually an interesting question. It probably depends on whether the check is done before or after the inline functions are being expanded (copy pasted for simple terms). If after, then the check should see the initialization. But if the check is done before it would not matter.

I would GUESS that this is compiler specific and that the standard does not mandate when/or even if a check like this is performed.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: On VS 2017 it doesn't matter if you define inline. And the code analysis is probably a VS specific implementation. Could very well be a program that runs that is not part of the compiler at all that does the analysis. Compiling in C++ Builder 10.3.1 gives no warning at all. Same is true for VS if you don't turn on Project -> Properties -> Code Analysis -> General -> Enable Code Analysis on Build

Comment: On VS 2017, pre-analysis is performed in the text editor, to highlight issues; this is done by an alternative tool. But I would be surprised that code inlining would be performed by another entity than the compiler.