# uninitialized float pointer

Tags: c++

I have this pointer in a struct, and it is used to fill the values of an array. it works as it should, but the Visual Studio keeps giving the same warning, saying that is uninitialized, and it's a NULL pointer, when it isn't.

Can anyone explain/help?

```
struct Sinal {
    int freq_amostra=0;
    int quant_amos_recol=0;
    float *val_amos;
};
void p() { system("pause"); };
Sinal lerficheiro();

int main()
{
    Sinal amostra;
    Sinal saida_rmo;
    Sinal saida_roc;
    Sinal saida_frc;

    int i,n;
    int opc_1, opc_2;

    char menu[6][50] = {{"Abrir ficheiro de amostras             "},{"Aplicar retifica‡„o de meia onda       "},{"Aplicar retifica‡„o de onda completa   "},{"Aplicar filtro RC                      "},{"Guardar ficheiro de resultados         "},{" Sair do programa                       "} };

    do {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t");
        printf("%c", 201);
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                printf("%c", 205);
            }
            printf("%c \n", 187);
            printf("\t");
            printf("%c", 186);
            printf("   Menu    ");
            printf("%c \n", 186);
            printf("\t");
            printf("%c", 200);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", 205);
        }
        printf("%c", 188);
        printf("\n");
        printf("%c", 201);
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", 205);
        }
        printf("%c", 203);
        for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", 205);
        }
        printf("%c \n", 187);
        for (n= 0; n < 6; n++)
        {
            if (n == 5)
            {
                printf("%c", 186);
                printf(" %d %c", n + 1, 186);
                printf("%s", menu[0, n]);
                printf("%c\n", 186);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", 186);
                printf(" %d %c %s", n + 1, 186, menu[0, n]);
                printf("%c \n", 186);
                printf("%c", 204);
                for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    printf("%c", 205);
                }
                printf("%c", 206);
                for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
                {
                    printf("%c", 205);
                }
                printf("%c \n", 185);
            }
        }
        printf("%c", 200);
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", 205);
        }
        printf("%c", 202);
        for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", 205);
        }
        printf("%c \n", 188);
        printf(" \n\n\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &opc_1);
        printf(" \n\n");
        switch (opc_1)
        {
        case 1:   // ler ficheiro
        {
            amostra=lerficheiro();

            printf(" \n");
            break;
        }
        case 2:    //retificação de meia onda
        { if (amostra.freq_amostra == NULL || amostra.quant_amos_recol == NULL)
        {
            printf("Deve escolher primeiro a op‡„o 1!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            saida_rmo.freq_amostra = amostra.freq_amostra;
            saida_rmo.quant_amos_recol = amostra.quant_amos_recol;
            saida_rmo.val_amos = (float*)malloc(amostra.quant_amos_recol * sizeof(float));

            for (int i = 0; i < amostra.quant_amos_recol; i++)
            {
                if (amostra.val_amos[i] > 0)
                {
                    saida_rmo.val_amos[i] = amostra.val_amos[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    saida_rmo.val_amos[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        }
        case 3:  // retificação de onda completa 
        {if (amostra.freq_amostra == NULL || amostra.quant_amos_recol == NULL)
        {
            printf("Deve escolher primeiro a op‡„o 1!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            saida_roc.freq_amostra = amostra.freq_amostra;
            saida_roc.quant_amos_recol = amostra.quant_amos_recol;
            saida_roc.val_amos = (float*)malloc(amostra.quant_amos_recol * sizeof(float));

            for (i = 0; i < amostra.quant_amos_recol; i++)
            {
                if (amostra.val_amos[i] >= 0)
                {
                    saida_roc.val_amos[i] = amostra.val_amos[i];
                }
                else if (amostra.val_amos[i] < 0)
                {
                    saida_roc.val_amos[i] = -amostra.val_amos[i];
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        }
        case 4:   // aplicação de filtro RC
        {if (amostra.freq_amostra == NULL || amostra.quant_amos_recol == NULL)
        {
            printf("Deve escolher primeiro a op‡„o 1!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            float res;
            float cond;
            double constante;
            double K1 = 0, K2 = 0;

            saida_frc.freq_amostra = amostra.freq_amostra;
            saida_frc.quant_amos_recol = amostra.quant_amos_recol;
            saida_frc.val_amos = (float*)malloc(amostra.quant_amos_recol * sizeof(float));
            constante = 1.0/ saida_frc.freq_amostra;

            do {
                printf("\nIndique o valor de resistencia:");
                scanf_s("%f", &res);
                printf("\nIndique o valor do condensador:");
                scanf_s("%f", &cond);
            } while (res== 0 || cond == 0);

            double frac_res_cond = (1.0/res)*(1.0/cond);

            for (int i = 1; i < amostra.quant_amos_recol; i++)
            {
                //K1 = (float)(frac_res_cond *((amostra.val_amos[i - 1]) - (saida_frc.val_amos[i - 1])));
                K1 = frac_res_cond *amostra.val_amos[i - 1] - frac_res_cond * saida_frc.val_amos[i - 1];
                //K2 = (float)(frac_res_cond *(amostra.val_amos[i] - saida_frc.val_amos[i - 1] + (K1 * constante)));
                K2 = frac_res_cond * amostra.val_amos[i] - frac_res_cond * saida_frc.val_amos[i - 1] + frac_res_cond * (K1 * constante);
                saida_frc.val_amos[i] = (saida_frc.val_amos[i - 1] + (constante*K1 + constante*K2) / 2);
            }
        }
        break;
        }
        case 5:   // guardar ficheiro
        {if (amostra.freq_amostra == NULL || amostra.quant_amos_recol == NULL)
        {
            printf("Deve escolher primeiro a op‡„o 1!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            FILE* fich_save;
            float* freq;
            char nome_fich_guardar[50];
            nome_fich_guardar[0] = '\0';
            char nome[30];
            char menu2[][50] = { { "Ficheiro de retifica‡„o de meia onda     "},{"Ficheiro de retifica‡„o de onda completa "},{ "Ficheiro de aplica‡„o de filtro RC        "}};

            do {
                printf("Nome do ficheiro a guardar: \n");
                scanf_s(" %s", nome_fich_guardar, 50);
            } while (strlen(nome_fich_guardar) < 1);

            strcpy(nome, nome_fich_guardar);
            strcat(nome, ".csv");
            printf("\n %s \n", nome);
            fich_save = fopen(nome, "w");

            freq = (float*)malloc(amostra.quant_amos_recol * sizeof(float));
            freq[0] = (0.0 / amostra.freq_amostra);
            for (int i = 1; i < amostra.quant_amos_recol; i++)
            {
                freq[i] = (1.0 / amostra.freq_amostra) + (freq[i - 1]);
            }

            do {
                system("cls");
                do {
                    printf("\t");
                    printf("%c", 201);
                    {
                        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
                        {
                            printf("%c", 205);
                        }
                        printf("%c \n", 187);
                        printf("\t");
                        printf("%c", 186);
                        printf(" Que ficheiro pretende guardar? ");
                        printf("%c \n", 186);
                        printf("\t");
                        printf("%c", 200);
                    }
                    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
                    {
                        printf("%c", 205);
                    }
                    printf("%c", 188);
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("%c", 201);
                    for (i = 0; i <3; i++)
                    {
                        printf("%c", 205);
                    }
                    printf("%c", 203);
                    for (i = 0; i < 42; i++)
                    {
                        printf("%c", 205);
                    }
                    printf("%c \n", 187);
                    for (n = 0; n < 3; n++)
                    {
                        if (n == 2)
                        {
                            printf("%c", 186);
                            printf(" %d %c", n + 1, 186);
                            printf("%s", menu2[0, n]);
                            printf("%c\n", 186);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("%c", 186);
                            printf(" %d %c %s", n + 1, 186, menu2[0, n]);
                            printf("%c \n", 186);
                            printf("%c", 204);
                            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                            {
                                printf("%c", 205);
                            }
                            printf("%c", 206);
                            for (i = 0; i < 42; i++)
                            {
                                printf("%c", 205);
                            }
                            printf("%c \n", 185);
                        }
                    }
                    printf("%c", 200);
                    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        printf("%c", 205);
                    }
                    printf("%c", 202);
                    for (i = 0; i < 42; i++)
                    {
                        printf("%c", 205);
                    }
                    printf("%c \n", 188);
                    printf(" \n\n\n");
                    scanf_s(" %d", &opc_2);

                } while (opc_2 < 1 || 3 < opc_2);
                switch (opc_2)
                {
                case 1: {
                    if (amostra.freq_amostra == NULL || amostra.quant_amos_recol == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("Deve escolher primeiro a op‡„o 2!\n");
                        p();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (amostra.quant_amos_recol == saida_rmo.quant_amos_recol)
                        {
                            for (i = 0; i < amostra.quant_amos_recol; i++)
                            {
                                fprintf(fich_save, " %.8f; %.8f; %.8f\n", freq[i], amostra.val_amos[i], saida_rmo.val_amos[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        else { exit(1); }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    if (amostra.freq_amostra == NULL || amostra.quant_amos_recol == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("Deve escolher primeiro a op‡„o 3!\n");
                        p();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (amostra.quant_amos_recol == saida_roc.quant_amos_recol)
                        {
                            for (i = 0; i < amostra.quant_amos_recol; i++)
                            {
                                fprintf(fich_save, " %.8f; %.8f; %.8f\n", freq[i], amostra.val_amos[i], saida_roc.val_amos[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        else { exit(1); }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    if (amostra.freq_amostra == NULL || amostra.quant_amos_recol == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("Deve escolher primeiro a op‡„o 4!\n");
                        p();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (amostra.quant_amos_recol == saida_frc.quant_amos_recol)
                        {
                            for (i = 0; i < amostra.quant_amos_recol; i++)
                            {
                                fprintf(fich_save, " %.8f; %.8f; %.8f\n", freq[i], amostra.val_amos[i], saida_frc.val_amos[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        else { exit(1); }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                }
            } while (opc_2 < 1 || 4 < opc_2);

            fclose(fich_save);
            printf("\n");
        }
        break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            exit(1);
            break;
        }
        }
    } while (1);
}
Sinal lerficheiro()
{    
    Sinal amostra;
    char local_fichlet[50];
    local_fichlet[0] = '\0';
    FILE* fichleitura;
    do {
        do {
            printf("Nome/localiza%c%co do ficheiro: ", 135, 132);
            scanf_s("%s", local_fichlet, 50);

        } while (strlen(local_fichlet) < 5);
        fichleitura = fopen(local_fichlet, "r");
        if (fichleitura == NULL)
        {
            printf("Erro ao abrir o ficheiro: %s \n", local_fichlet);
            system("pause");
        }
    } while (fichleitura == NULL);

    fscanf_s(fichleitura, "%d", &amostra.freq_amostra);
    fscanf_s(fichleitura, "%d", &amostra.quant_amos_recol);

    amostra.val_amos = (float*)malloc(amostra.quant_amos_recol*sizeof(float));

    for (int i = 0; i < amostra.quant_amos_recol; i++)
    {
        fscanf_s(fichleitura, "%f", &amostra.val_amos[i]);
    }
    fclose(fichleitura);
    return amostra;
}
```

> C26495    Variable 'Sinal::val_amos' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).

Comment: 1. Why are you using `malloc` in C++? 2. Why aren't you using a `std::vector<float>` instead of a `float*`?

Comment: Also which line(s) are giving this warning? There's way too much code here for a [mcve]

Comment: I don’t see that you initialize `amostra.val_amos` anywhere.

Comment: There is ZERO ````C++```` code. Please change the tag to ````C````

Comment: Way too much code. Chop out all the menu stuff, remove anything else that doesn't contribute to the problem, and show the **smallest** code you can come up with that shows the error.

Comment: `Sinal` is not a typedeffed type in C. Please dont confuse C and C++.

Comment: @Armin The `typedef struct` won't work in `C` (neither will the initializers therein) - this will only compile in `C++` .

Comment: But there are many other errors/warning/issues in this code!

Comment: Tag was changed from C++ to C by mistake, I believe. I reverted it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning C26495 function invocation from constructor to initialize variable, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54866097/warning-c26495-function-invocation-from-constructor-to-initialize-variable-why)

Comment: @anatolyg I guess I posted my answer too hastily - I should *really* have looked for a dupe (as you did). I'll leave it for now - but may delete later, if that seems appropriate.

Comment: @anatolyg No, this wasn't a mistake. Even though the code doesn't compile as C, doesn't make it any more C++.

Comment: @Olaf - It's a weird hybrid of C and C++, actually.

Comment: @OlafDietsche The [C++ tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) says to tag as C++ if it's being compiled with a C++ compiler. Even if it's ugly C++, it is valid C++, and not valid C.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for clarifying, I missed that.

Comment: What makes you think the pointer is NULL? Nowhere in your code do you assign NULL to anything. Pointers aren't NULL by default.

Comment: If they enter any other number before `1` then you use `amostra` which has not been initialized  (it was only assigned to in the case 1) .

Comment: @ArminMontigny some code is valid C and valid C++  , the site policy is that the question should be tagged according to which compiler the OP is using (or intends to use anyway) . Not according to aesthetic preferences of the commentors

Answer (score 2):

You can address this warning by giving the `val_amos` structure member an initial (default) value in the declaration of `Sinal`, just as you have done with the other members:

```cpp
struct Sinal {
    int freq_amostra=0;
    int quant_amos_recol=0;
    float *val_amos = nullptr;
};
```

Without this (as you have not defined a constructor for `Sinal`) the `val_amos` member will have an **uninitialized** (i.e. *undefined* = anything/random) value when an object of type `Sinal` is first created.

Also, the other warning you hinted at:

> warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'amostra.val_amos'.

Can be fixed by *explicitly* checking that the value returned by `malloc` is not `NULL`:

```cpp
    amostra.val_amos = (float*)malloc(amostra.quant_amos_recol * sizeof(float));
    if (amostra.val_amos) for (int i = 0; i < amostra.quant_amos_recol; i++)
    {
        fscanf_s(fichleitura, "%f", &amostra.val_amos[i]);
    }
```

*However, I have to agree with the points made by many in the comments that your code is not really using `C++` as it should be used - you seem to have taken some old `C` code and quickly adapted it to work as `C++`.*

Comment: Silencing the warning just hides the bug. It doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Actually, the two suggestions I have made *do address* the ***causes*** of the warnings. Perhaps my use of the word 'silence' is misleading? (But I agree 100% that the code needs considerably more work to make it bug-free!)

Comment: @ProXicT - Thanks for the edit!  Would you care to edit the other use of "silenced?" ‎

Comment: @AdrianMole Sure, I didn't even notice this one, to be honest.